# where is git-daemon?

Tags: ubuntu-10.10, git

according to man `git-daemon`, this comes with the git package, althought i've look in /etc/init.d and /usr/bin/git* and i can't find where this is

```
$ git --version
git version 1.7.1
$ whereis git-daemon
git-daemon: /usr/share/man/man1/git-daemon.1.gz
```

this is on ubuntu 10.10 x86_64

from [this post](http://ao2.it/wiki/How_to_setup_a_GIT_server_with_gitosis_and_gitweb) it seems that you might create the script, althought it is not clear what is the script/command that the manpage is referring to

Does this comes with a separate package now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's installed it should be at `/usr/lib/git-core/git-daemon` but you may have to install it with `apt-get install git-daemon`

Comment: yeah its in there.. /usr/lib ..wtf place to put an executable

Comment: @lurscher You can always symlink it to /usr/bin to make it easier to access. Just as an FYI you can use `find / --name git-daemon` to run a system search for it in future. Whereis will only show stuff on the system path